# Add "Plus VAT" label but only on products with VAT

Tags: magento-1.9, vat

My 1.9.4 site is predominantly Food so does not incur VAT. 
I have my Site set to show Prices without VAT.
I do not want to show prices with and without VAT.
I'd like to add a label to the end of the Price reading "+VAT" but only if that product is taxable.

Any suggestions will be gratefully received.
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You can check check in your templates in which your product object is available for the `taxClassId` attribute.

The `taxClassId` stores the information about the tax class assigned to a product for example in admin panel. `taxClassId = 0` means the product has no tax class, `taxClassId > 0` means the product has a specific tax class.

For example you can use the following code in `catalog/product/price.phtml` template:

```
$_vatSuffix = '';
if ($_product->getTaxClassId()){
  $_vatSuffix = ' +VAT';
}
[...]
<?php echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_finalPriceInclTax, false) . $_vatSuffix ?>
```

This is only an example to show, how you can identify the products with VAT and based on that information add a price suffix. You will have to change some other templates depending on your theme and customization.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Altering this file doesn't seem to change the ./public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml

Is this possibly down to Caching?

Comment: you have to make the changes in the template your theme is using, the default Magento file I referred to is app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/price.html without bundle :-)

Comment: @Russell you're welcome. Please let me know if you need further help on this issue